# Pandas Loc select by index as well as boolean condition in single expression

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simplified Dataframe which can be set up as follows:

```
indexes =['01/10/2017', '28/10/2018', '27/10/2019', '30/10/2019']
cols = ['Period', 'A', 'B', 'C']
df= pd.DataFrame(index = indexes, columns= cols)
df.Period = 1
df = pd.concat([df, 2*df.copy(), 3*df.copy()])
df.sort_index()
```

The Dataframe looks like:

```
    Period        A      B       C
01/10/2017  1   NaN     NaN     NaN
01/10/2017  2   NaN     NaN     NaN
01/10/2017  3   NaN     NaN     NaN
27/10/2019  1   NaN     NaN     NaN
27/10/2019  2   NaN     NaN     NaN
27/10/2019  3   NaN     NaN     NaN
28/10/2018  1   NaN     NaN     NaN
28/10/2018  2   NaN     NaN     NaN
28/10/2018  3   NaN     NaN     NaN
30/10/2019  1   NaN     NaN     NaN
30/10/2019  2   NaN     NaN     NaN
30/10/2019  3   NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I want to find the rows that are in this list:

`FwdTimeChangeDates = ['28/10/2018', '27/10/2019']`

with `Period` that is `> 2`.

I want to `+=2` to the Period with those conditions (So Period `3`-->`5`, and `4`-->`6`, etc.).

How do I filter based on the two conditions?

`df.loc[FwdTimeChangeDates]` Gives:

`Period  A   B   C
28/10/2018  1   NaN     NaN     NaN
28/10/2018  2   NaN     NaN     NaN
28/10/2018  3   NaN     NaN     NaN
27/10/2019  1   NaN     NaN     NaN
27/10/2019  2   NaN     NaN     NaN
27/10/2019  3   NaN     NaN     NaN`

and

`df.loc[df.Period>2]`

Gives

`Period  A   B   C
01/10/2017  3   NaN     NaN     NaN
28/10/2018  3   NaN     NaN     NaN
27/10/2019  3   NaN     NaN     NaN
30/10/2019  3   NaN     NaN     NaN`

and I want:

`Period  A   B   C
28/10/2018  3   NaN     NaN     NaN
27/10/2019  3   NaN     NaN     NaN`

But I can't join the two conditions with:

`df.loc[FwdTimeChangeDates & df.Period>1]` or
`df.loc[(FwdTimeChangeDates) & (df.Period>1)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine the two conditions, use `isin` for the first.

```
df[df.index.isin(['28/10/2018', '27/10/2019']) & (df.Period > 2)]

            Period    A    B    C
28/10/2018       3  NaN  NaN  NaN
27/10/2019       3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

If the dataframe has a multiindex:

```
df.loc[(df.index.isin(FwdTimeChangeDates, level=0)) & (df.Period > 2), 'Period']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split two conditions

```
df.loc[FwdTimeChangeDates].query('Period>2')
Out[1366]: 
            Period    A    B    C
28/10/2018       3  NaN  NaN  NaN
27/10/2019       3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, never used query before. How could I use it to +=2 like ColdSpeed, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @AH you mean `df.loc[FwdTimeChangeDates].query('Period>=2')` ?

Comment: I mean, using query, how can I change the Periods to go from 3 --> 5, like: 
`Period    A    B    C
28/10/2018       5  NaN  NaN  NaN
27/10/2019       5  NaN  NaN  NaN`